# why do i get those weird black spots on a baked roughness map?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, roughness

i was trying to bake the roughness map.
but for some reason it got those weird black marking on it. that were not originaly there.
i have no idea why it happens.

any idea how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: May be wrong face direction or overlapping geometry.

Comment: no, i checked the normal and they are fine,
its also impossible for for vertices to overlap. cuse its just a UV sphere there is only place at the front were i edtited its the geometry
but this is not were the issues are coming from/
another things to point out

is that when i exported the model as FBX file and appended to a new project.
the baking worked.

another issue i have now is trhat when im baking. the noise on the texture looks different

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem very similar to this.  I after much trial and error and using different colors, I finally figured out that you MUST have the "roughness" setting of your materials set to less than 1.  If I painted a model with any color with a Roughness set to 1, then it would be mostly Black with few correctly colored spots when imported into Monogame as an FBX.